# Install Confluent Platform inside docker Ubuntu container on Windows 10

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I am trying to install Confluent Platform on my Windows machine. As far as I know, installing Confluent Platform will give me access to KSQL which is not available in Apache Kafka package. The other hurdle is : KSQL can't run on windows directly, it requires Unix environment. As I am on Windows so my options are limited.
I explored below options :

> 1. I tried to use Windows Subsystem for Linux, but installing anything from Windows App Store is
>    restricted in my environment. So, it's not possible to install Ubuntu from app store.
> 2. As I have docker installed on my system. I am planning to pull Ubuntu image and run Kafka inside it. I pulled Ubuntu image from Docker hub. Now, I need to download confluent-platform. I am planning to download it using WGET but not sure about the URL or path that I need to provide to wget.

Please suggest me the path to download confluent package.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel when a developer image would suffice? Does any of [these images](https://hub.docker.com/search?q=kafka&type=image) work?

Comment: Thanks for the response !! My confusion is I am already running Ubuntu container in Docker so do I have to run another one for Kafka ? If yes, then how will I communicate between two or Can I just run Kafka container? Sorry, I am just confused..

Comment: If you're not using Ubuntu for anything, you can get rid of it and simply run the Kafka image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please suggest me the path to download confluent package

Try the Confluent website??

> As far as I know, installing Confluent Platform will give me access to KSQL which is not available in Apache Kafka package.

First, it's now referred to as ksqlDB. Second, it works with any Kafka provider. Confluent provides Apache Kafka as part of their distribution

You can use ksqlDB container with Apache Kafka running on Windows

Or you can run everything in containers, as shown in the quickstart - https://ksqldb.io/quickstart.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-kafka/) instead of the bare bones ubuntu image.

It runs a Debian base, so apt-get will still work if you want to extend it